# Show JSON with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have following PHP code

```
 $val="<div id=user".$row['cid']." userid=".$row['cid']." class=innertxt><img src=images/images.jpg width=50 height=50><strong>".$uname."</strong><ul> <li>Email: ".$row['cemail']."</li> <li> <input type=checkbox id=select".$row['cid']." value=".$row['cid']." class=selectit /></li> </ul> </div>" ;

 $return["foo"] =$val;

 print json_encode($return);
```

but once i get result i get in following format ?

```
<div id=user11 userid=11 class=innertxt>
    <img src=images\/images.jpg width=50 height=50>
    <strong>Ruby<\/strong>
    <ul>
        <li>Email: ruby@qualityhouse.ae<\/li>
        <li> <input type=checkbox id=select11 value=11 class=selectit \/><\/li> 
    <\/ul> 
<\/div>
```

why i am getting this / and how to solve it?

Comment: Your result should be in JSON format

Comment: What are you doing with the JSON-encoded text?  Why are you JSON-encoding that HTML fragment in the first place?

Comment: How are you decoding the json'd data?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around values? e.g id='user11' instead of id=user11

Comment: @Sagi, Although that is valid, I don't think its related to the `\/` occurrence. It might be an *escaping* issue, plus I am not exactly sure why its being in encoded in JSON.

Comment: In place of $val = "<div>".$string."</div>", use $val = "<div>$string</val>". Its faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stripslashes` method can be used. Checkout the following snippet:

```
print stripslashes(json_encode($return));
```

more details can be found at the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Answer (score 1):

Slashes should be escaped with a backslash, so the output is correct.

Try this:

```
var x = eval({ var: "<\/div>" });
alert(x.var);
```

It will produce the correct output. (`</div>`)

The interesting thing is, that you got a string, instead of an object. Are you sure that the code fragment is correct? Because it shoud be:

```
{ foo: <div id=user11 userid=11 class=innertxt><img src=images\/images.jpg width=50 height=50><strong>Ruby<\/strong><ul> <li>Email: ruby@qualityhouse.ae<\/li> <li> <input type=checkbox id=select11 value=11 class=selectit \/><\/li> <\/ul> 
<\/div> }
```

Are you sure you wrote `json_encode($return)`, instead of `json_encode($return['foo'])`?